# How do I put <methods> inside a proguard XML (ant script) to exclude all methods but not variables?

Tags: java, ant, proguard, xsbt-proguard-plugin

I am trying to preserve all methods, but not the variables and member variables of a class:

I am inside an ant script so the two options below do not work:

```
-keepclassmembers class sun.** {
    <methods>
}


-keepclassmembers class sun.** {
    &lt;methods&gt;
}
```

It complains about the '<' and '>'.

All I want to do is exclude the methods but not the variables :(

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax inside Ant is with `&lt;` and `&gt;`. For instance, from `proguard/examples/ant/applications2.xml`:

```
<proguard>
    -keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
        native &lt;methods&gt;;
    }
</proguard>
```

Note that this results in a double semi-colon at the end of the line.